# Is it possible to use D-Wave systems for free?

Tags: resource-request, d-wave

IBM offers its platform IBM Q for free with certain constraints, such as available quantum processors and number of jobs running in parallel.

I was wondering whether there is the same possibility on D-Wave quantum annealers. I looked at D-Wave web page but I was not able to find any useful information.

**Does anyone have any experience with  D-Wave and possibility to at least sign up for free to some trial version?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [D-Wave leap](https://www.dwavesys.com/take-leap).
It is free for sign up, and you can get trial access time.